# How to use JSON data (array) from PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I would like to retrieve each element inside of `this.responseText`, and put them in my HTML on Javascript. Is there something wrong in my code? I hope my code helps you to understand my question. Thanks.
(p.s. the html code is provided, and so I cannot use jquery.)

an example of `this.responseText` is below; (By using `alert`, I got that)

```
{"name":"Hermione Grainger","number":"4","review":"Not as good as the NEXT book in the series, but hilarious and satisfying."}{"name":"Ronald Drumpf","number":"1","review":"Feminist propaganda!"}{"name":"Brienne of Tarth","number":"5","review":"Alanna is my best friend."}
```

And my java script is below;

```
function bookReview(){
    var reviews = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(var i=0; i<reviews.length; i++){
        var name = document.createElement("h3");
        var text = document.createElement("p");
        name.innerHTML = reviews[i].name + reviews[i].number;
        text.innerHTML = reviews[i].review;

        document.getElementById("reviews").appendChild(name);
        document.getElementById("reviews").appendChild(text);
    }
}
```

or is there something wrong in my PHP code??

```
$path = "books/$book/";
review(glob($path . "review" . "*" . ".txt"));

function review($reviews) {
    foreach ($reviews as $each) {
        $review = file($each, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $output = array (
            "name" => $review[0],
            "number" => $review[1],
            "review" => $review[2]
            );
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesnt look like valid JSON, should be like '[{},{},{}]'. If you want you can use a JSON validator, e.g. http://json-validator.com/.

To generate the JSON array properly you can do:

```
$array = [];
foreach ($reviews as $each) {
    $review = file($each, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $output = array (
        "name" => $review[0],
        "number" => $review[1],
        "review" => $review[2]
        );
    array_push($array,$review);
}
print(json_encode($array));
```

Comment: I added my PHP code. Can you check my PHP code, please??

Comment: see 2nd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739871/how-to-create-an-array-for-json-using-php (generate the arrays in the loop, then outside of it put them in an array and json.encode this one).

Comment: I changed it to the code below, but it did not work well...
 function review($reviews) {
  foreach ($reviews as $each) {
   $review = file($each, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
   $output = array (
    array(
     "name" => $review[0],
     "number" => $review[1],
     "review" => $review[2]
     )
    );
   
  }
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  print(json_encode($output));
 }

Comment: Each $output = array (...); in the loop just generates one datastructure, you have to put them all in an array (see my edit).  Also $output is only available in the block it is declared in (aka the inside of the for loop), or at least i guess php handles it this way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can understand that!

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this exemple for ajax:

AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'Json',
        data: {'q': val_1},
        success: function (response) {
           var newhref;
           var newhrefid;
           var div=document.getElementById("myDropdown"); 
           for(var i = 0; i<response.nunber_of_rows; i++){
             newhref= document.createElement("a");
             newhref.href= response.tabel[i];
             newhref.innerHTML= response.tabel[i];
             newhrefid = "idhr_"+i;
             newhref.setAttribute('id', newhrefid );
             div.appendChild(newhref);
           } 
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
...//your code
echo json_encode (array(
                    'tabel'=>$tabel,
                    'nunber_of_rows'=>$nunber_of_rows
));
```

In this example you define, that you are using Json with this line of code:

```
datatype = "Json";
```

In your php you send back the data through:

```
echo json_encode (array(
                    'tabel'=>$tabel,
                    'nunber_of_rows'=>$nunber_of_rows
));
```

To use the data in your ajax:

```
response.nunber_of_rows
```

The example it's from this link [How to use Ajax and JSON for making dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827637/how-to-use-ajax-and-json-for-making-dropdown-menu/44049544#44049544)

If you do not want to use AJAX:

PHP:

```
$phpArray = array(
          0 => "Mon", 
          1 => "Tue", 
          2 => "Wed", 
          3 => "Thu",
          4 => "Fri", 
          5 => "Sat",
          6 => "Sun",

    )
```

JS:

```
    var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;

    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        alert(jArray[i]);
    }
```

To get the php array you need only to do this:

```
var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;
```

The example it's from this link [Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function)

To use JSON.parse:

```
var data = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>' );
```

Example:

PHP:

```
<?php
$books = array(
    array(
        "title" => "Professional JavaScript",
        "author" => "Nicholas C. Zakas"
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
        "author" => "David Flanagan"
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "High Performance JavaScript",
        "author" => "Nicholas C. Zakas"
    )
);
?>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// using JSON.parse on the output of json_encode
var books = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($books); ?>' );

/* output (with some whitespace added for readability)
[
    {"title":"Professional JavaScript", "author":"Nicholas C. Zakas"},
    {"title":"JavaScript: The Definitive Guide", "author":"David Flanagan"},
    {"title":"High Performance JavaScript", "author":"Nicholas C. Zakas"}
]
*/

// how to access
console.log( books[1].author ); // David Flanagan
</script>
```

Now to get a value from your original array, you just have to use:

```
books[1].author
```

The example it's from this link http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/parse.php