# How to access 2nd level of a dynamic menu (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a menu which works perfect for 1st and 2nd level only, but I need to go deeper and show all sub levels.
The menu is something like this when it loads:

```
<ul id="mnav" style="padding-top: 80px; background-color: #337ab7;">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a id="<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>" class="list-group-item active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

And I want to have sublevels like this or maybe somehow you offer.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub item 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">about</a>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To achieve this, I'm using such a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('ul#mnav > li > a').on('click', function(e) { 
            console.log("Level 1"); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var cat = $(this).attr('id'); 
            var url = 'index.php?route=test/categoryx/child&category_id=' + cat; 

            $('#mnav #sub1').remove(); 
            $( $("<ul class='sub' id='sub1'>").load(url + "#myContainer") ).insertAfter( '#mnav #' + cat );
        }); 

        $('ul#sub1 a').on('click', function(e) { 
            console.log("Level 2"); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var cat = $(this).attr('id'); 
            var url = 'index.php?route=test/categoryx/child&category_id=' + cat; 

            $('#sub2').remove(); 
            $( $("<ul class='sub' id='sub2'>").load(url + "#myContainer") ).insertAfter( 'ul#sub1 #' + cat );
        }); 
</script>
```

I tried different ways to get access to 2nd level but it's not successful, I tried many different things.

Comment: Are you sure about this: `append($("<div id='sub'>")` ? I think you need to close the div: `append($("<div id='sub'></div>")`.

Comment: Is this the result html of your php file? If yes, there is not element with `id="sub1`. And your links has not id. And this is not a jquery selector`$( $("<ul class='sub' id='sub1'>")` instead you need to write some thing like this: `$('ul.sub')` or `$('#sub1')` ... And do not use two `$` . My friend, I think you need more studies in jquery.

Comment: And also this is not true: `insertAfter( '#mnav #' + cat )` .. instead write this: `insertAfter($( '#mnav #' + cat) )`

Comment: @FarzinKanzi: Thanks a lot! The problem got fixed :-)

Comment: You welcome my friend....